# AspxGridView ObjectDataSource sorting

Tags: asp.net, sorting, devexpress, objectdatasource, aspxgridview

I'm porting from ASP.NET GridView to DevExpress AspxGridView, and I'm using the same ObjectDataSource, but now when I click on header it throws:

> "The data source 'xxx' does not support sorting with IEnumerable data.
>   Automatic sorting is only supported with DataView, DataTable, and
>   DataSet."

But this worked well for GridView, so I doubt it is really a fault of 'xxx'. On the old gridview paging, and sorting was fine. Now paging still works (when I use "DataSourceForceStandardPaging").

How to make it work with AspxGridView?

Comment: you can use customsorting to implement sorting in the aspxgridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement ASPxGridView sorting using custom rules, it is necessary to set the column's [Settings.SortMode](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewGridViewDataColumnSettings_SortModetopic) property to "`Custom`" and handle the [ASPxGridView.CustomColumnSort](http://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_CustomColumnSorttopic.aspx) event (as it illustrated in the corresponding topic). However, the **Settings.AllowSort** option should not be disabled.

**Custom Sorting example:**

```
RepositoryItemHyperLinkEdit hlnkEditor;
private void GridCustomSortTest_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string[] months = new string[] { "January", "February", "March", 
        "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", 
        "October", "November", "December" };
    hlnkEditor = new RepositoryItemHyperLinkEdit();
    //hlnkEditor.Buttons[0].Kind = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.ButtonPredefines.Glyph;

    grid.DataSource = months;
    grid.RefreshDataSource();
    gridView1.Columns[0].SortMode = DevExpress.XtraGrid.ColumnSortMode.Custom;
    gridView1.Columns[0].ColumnEdit = hlnkEditor;
    gridView1.CustomColumnSort += new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnSortEventHandler(gridView1_CustomColumnSort);


}

void gridView1_CustomColumnSort(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnSortEventArgs e)
{
    e.Result = Comparer<int>.Default.Compare(e.ListSourceRowIndex1,
       e.ListSourceRowIndex2);

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Hope this help..

**Edit:**
For Server side sorting and paging please go through example -
[Bind a grid to a ObjectDataSource with EnablePaging](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2672) and there also check the see also links.

More References:
[How can I get the grid to sort my ObjectDataSource on the server?](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q200215)
[Passing Gridview Paging/Sorting/Grouping/Filtering expressions to business logic Select Methods](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q235764)
[ASPxGridView - ObjectDataSource Paging and Filtering](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q291332)
[Performance comparison of XPO and Entity Frameworks, and ObjectDataSource](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q363849)

**Binding with Large data:**
[Binding to Data](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument3719)
[Binding to Large Data (Database Server Mode)](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument14781)
[A possible implementation of IListServer interface to achieve Server Mode functionality](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E166)

Comment: Sorry, it was night here. Will this work with paging, or will it sort only the actual page (client sorting)? I need server-side sorting. It worked well before. A "order by" column was sent to GetData method, and I sorted data on server-side. This didn't changed, but AspxGridView throws that weird message.

Comment: Are you there? How can I implement server sorting rather (I have 100,000 rows)?

Comment: I'm checking it out. I was reading the "Bind a grid to a..." article at that time. So I guess I need to convert objects to DataTable. Because I won't send DT across the client/server boundary (it gets serialized to xml => ~10x size). So I'll need to construct it one client-side. It is unclear to me why DT works, and plain list doesn't (mainly sorting). As I'm returning already sorted data portion (page). Probably some if (source is DataTable) somewhere.

Comment: I did try the IListSource, and it returned first page only (other were empty), but it didn't reacted when I clicked on column header -> i.e. sorting. I've tried ObjectDataSource (converting output to DataTable). Paging still works okay, and sorting is not throwing exception, but it doesn't react to header click as well. Should I invoke it somehow manually? (when I click sort, and then uncached page, it requests data with updated/correct "orderBy" parameter)

Comment: The grid performs only client-side sorting, I'm still unable to force it to request page data when column header is clicked.

Comment: OK. Some progress, I was able to repair IListServer implementation (turned off Sort Custom mode). And some other streamlining. Now it displays data correctly, and is also reacting to sort end-user action.